# XMPP Multiple tabs synchronize sent message

Tags: session, xmpp, openfire, strophe

I am implementing an Openfire chat client in a web site with Strophe.js. I managed to get multiple sessions and multiple windows reloading page and reconnecting back. Now I have challenge in restoring the chat history.
But the first issue I am stuck at when a user opens two tabs of our site it creates two xmpp sessions with different resource ID's but now say 
a@example.com/tab1 sent a message to friend this should be synchronized in tab2

Example if you send chat message from gtalk user sent message will be updated and showin in gmail chat window.

Any one has any idea.
Thanks you very much for the time and help.

Answer (score 1):

The routing logic for multiple resources is up to the server implementation. The GTalk server routes messages sent to **bare Jids** to all connected resources. Many other servers (also Openfire) send messages to bare Jids to the **most available resource**, which is the one with the highest priority.

If each of your tabs has its own resource then I suggest to send the messages to each resource (**full jid**) manual. You get all connected resources of your subscribed contacts with the presence.

Comment: You are talking about sending messages so that they are received by all resources. What about synchronizing sent messages? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is. Have a look at XEP-0280: Message Carbons ( http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0280.html )

Both your client as well as your server have to support it in order to fully work.

Source : https://superuser.com/questions/866785/is-there-a-way-to-sync-xmpp-messages-across-different-devices-with-standard-xmp