# Count total XMPP session in multiple tabs/window

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

I also have a same problem as mentioned [here](https://github.com/sstrigler/JSJaC/issues/41). But, I went ahead with the approach of randomizing my resource so as to maintain the session in multiple tabs/windows. Also, I get carbon message ([LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30055048/2968762)) in all tabs/windows.

My only concern is, I'm saving chat history using (store.js) in my browser. And if 5 tabs are opened, then message gets saved 5 times. Which is a repeat.

**How can I determine to how many tabs/windows the message was sent?**

Based on the count I want to apply my logic to save the message only once.

Answer (score 0):

You can count the number of tabs from Javascript because, you are sandbox to your own tab for security reason.

However, what you can do is ensure your client have unique id on the message tag and you can check on write if your message has already been written in your store or not.

Comment: Hi Thanks for replying. I have following issues:

1> Counting number of tabs becomes browser specific, but it won't work for multiple and different browser windows
2> I can't have a unique ID, as I depend on the key stored in storejs, using which I show chat history. Like your suggestion, I already thought of saving it wrt xmpp resource, but again resource changes every page reload

Comment: I assume you are building an online service and thus control the client. You should make sure the sending client adds a unique id. You could use that one for storage.